# Adjust mathfont with \fontdimen in preamble errors

Tags: fonts, preamble

I am using a custom math font using the `\setmathfont` command from unicode-math. However the exponents don't render properly and are set too low. To adjust this I am using the following:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
 \setbox0=\hbox{
  \check@mathfonts{
   \fontdimen16\textfont2=2.5pt
   \fontdimen17\textfont2=2.5pt
   \fontdimen14\textfont2=4.5pt
   \fontdimen13\textfont2=4.5pt
  }
 }
}
```

However this is giving me a ton of errors such as `Extra }, or forgotten $.` and `Improper \prevdepth.` on my title page. Everything seem to render fine in the PDF but I got 6 additional annoying errors. Is there a way to fix these? I am using overleaf.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you forgot the `\makeatletter` before the `\AtBeginDocument`. And next time show a small but *complete* example, then one doesn't have to guess.

Comment: \makeatletter seems to have fixed it... Thanks a lot!! I am quite new to using TeX and I read elsewhere on this StackExchange the same complaint to include a whole compilable example and thought of sharing my whole Overleaf project instead? The preamble is really large and have many commercial font files included so I was hesitant to do so, and trying to replicate the error in a shorter format here felt futile for what I thought was an easy question. I'll try harder in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: No you should not share an overleaf project. Such links will be dead over time and make your question useless for other people. I at least won't follow such links.  Provide a small and complete example here.